# Ajax post data format

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is it possible to format the data like so?

```
{name: $('#elementId').text()}
```

I have tried many options, but nothing seems to work. I get ajax success but no data is sent to the server. The return value is null.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ReportTest.php",
    data: {machineId: $('#FormOverviewMachineID').text()},
    success: function(output){
        console.log(jQuery.parseJSON(output));
    }
})
```

Any help on this would be fantastic. I feel like I'm pretty close.

Thanks.

*Edit:*

My PHP is like so (for testing):

```
$MachineID = $_POST['machineID'];
print_r($MachineID);
```

I can also print the values to the console before using them in the ajax request like so

```
machineIdTest = $('#FormOverviewMachineID').text();
console.log("MachineID: "+machineIdTest);
```

This returns the value fine.

***Final Edit***

Okay okay, I was dumb but thanks for the responses.

Typo: **machineId** =/= **machineID**

And thanks for the mention about parsing the response in JSON.

Cheers everyone!

Comment: Can you show what `$("#elementId");` contains?

Comment: FormOverviewMachineID, is it a div id or input id, if input try this way, $('#FormOverviewMachineID').val()

Comment: `success` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. Instead, use `.done()`

Comment: Can show the content of `ReportTest.php`?

Comment: How do you know no data is being sent? The Net tab of Firebug will show you exactly what has been snt, and what is being returned.

Comment: Cheers for the quick responses! It is a table cell  with an id <td id="FormOverviewMachineId">3Stand</td>

Comment: `machineId` and `machineID`.  Can you spot the difference? ;)

Comment: Kindly post your html also so that we can understand your question properly.

Comment: Archer already gave you the answer (in comments, now posted as an answer), you're creating a parameter in the request with a lower case D (`machineId`) then trying to access a POST variable called `machineID` with an upper case D. Voting to close because this essentially boils down to being a typo question.

Comment: @arbitter The `.success()` function is deprecated, but that's entirely separate to the `success` property passed when calling `$.ajax()`.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: right, my bad! Got a little confused, I guess with `.done()` confusion will be avoided :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your script to this...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ReportTest.php",
    data: {machineID: $('#FormOverviewMachineID').text()},
    success: function(output){
        console.log(output);
    }
});
```

I've only made 1 small change.  You originally passed the data variable `machineId`, but then looked for `machineID` in PHP.  They're different names in your post (uppercase/lowercase D).

Comment: Oh balls. Well you found it! But now its returning "Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Number"

Comment: @DanielMason You're trying to parse the response as JSON but your response **isn't** JSON.

Comment: The smallest and simplest things are sometimes the most time consuming and confusing :)  And as Anthony says above, it's not JSON.  I've modified the script to remove the parseJSON.

Comment: Thanks very much I shall walk through **each** step next time. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the data outside the ajax call:

```
var machineIdValue = $('#FormOverviewMachineID').text();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ReportTest.php",
    data: {machineId: machineIdValue},
    success: function(output){
        console.log(jQuery.parseJSON(output));
    }
})
```

Breakpoint on the machineIdValue assignment line and then check its value in the console.

Comment: I have tried this and the console is still coming back with null :/

Answer (score 0):

**yes possible**

```
$('#FormOverviewMachineID').val() instead of $('#FormOverviewMachineID').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a table cell so you can use 
`$('#FormOverviewMachineID').html()` to get its value.

Try and let me know.